React Routers MemoryRouter does not work as expected when given a basename prop
For some reason, I struggle alot with getting the MemoryRouter to render Routes when I supply a basename prop to the url.
I made an example demonstrating what I mean here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/memory-router-woes-hmt5mn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx
I want my router to render routes under the basename "/web"
So, if the user visits "/web/" it should render PageOne. If a user hits "/web/list" it should render PageTwo.
I try to achieve this by configuring my MemoryRouter like this:
<MemoryRouter basename="/web">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<PageOne />} />
          <Route path="/list" element={<PageTwo />} />
        </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>

The routes never render, and I just can't understand why. I am sure there must be something obvious/basic I am not seeing here.
Can you spot what I have missed?
I am using React Router v6.23.1
I tried to run this code without the basename prop and made sure to visit an url without the /web suffix. This works as expected. Once I add the basename prop and visit the url with the /web suffix, it will not render any of the routes.

After asking other people, one of my collegaues pointed out that this works as expected when the MemoryRouter is initialized with an 'initalEntries=["/web"]'
I updated my sandbox to reflect it:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/memory-router-woes-hmt5mn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx

Check your console logs, there is a warning regarding the basename prop and why nothing is rendered:

<Router basename="/web"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it
does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render
anything.

Complete error:
 <Router basename="/web"> is not able to match the URL "/" because it does not start with the basename, so the <Router> won't render anything. 
    at Router (https://hmt5mn.csb.app/node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js:1059:18)
    at MemoryRouter (https://hmt5mn.csb.app/node_modules/react-router/dist/index.js:1007:18)
    at div
    at App

The sandbox is served from "/" so there is a mismatch between it and the memory router's basename prop and so the router won't render anything. When you build and deploy the app and serve/host it from some ".../web" sub-directory the basename prop should work as you are expecting.
If you want, you could probably conditionally apply which basename value to use depending on the build type.
Example:
const basename = process.env.REACT_APP_NODE_ENV === "development"
  ? "/"
  : "/web";

...

<MemoryRouter basename={basename}>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<PageOne />} />
    <Route path="/list" element={<PageTwo />} />
  </Routes>
</MemoryRouter>

Note that in the sandbox it's process.env.NODE_ENV that you would reference.
